# How to decode route points from the JSON Output Data?

Tags: ios, xcode, json, google-maps, mkmapview

I am new in the `ios` field, Now i am trying to implement `MKMapView` Based iPhone Application. From the Google Map Web web service i Fetch the Data in `JSON` Output Format.

```
- (void)update {

    self.responseData=[NSMutableData data];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Ernakulam&destination=Kanyakumari&mode=driving&sensor=false"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];    
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    [self.responseData setLength:0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [connection release];
    self.responseData =nil;
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"connection established");
    [connection release];
    NSString *responseString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.responseData=nil;
    NSLog(@" OUTPUT JSON DATA^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^%@",responseString);


}
```

I got the out put has in the `JSON` Format. Now i want to draw route between this two location. sow how can i  separate all the latitude and Longitude points from the `JSON` out put Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this code. I am using JSONkit for parsing

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"connection established");
    [connection release];
    NSString *responseString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableDictionary *data1 = [responseData objectFromJSONData];
    NSMutableArray *ad = [data1 objectForKey:@"routes"];
    NSMutableArray *data2 = [[ad objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"legs"];
    NSMutableArray *data3 = [[data2 objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"steps"];
//    NSLog(@"Data3 %@", data3);
    for(int i = 0; i<data3.count;i++){
        NSLog(@"Start %@", [[data3 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"start_location"]);
        NSLog(@"End %@", [[data3 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"end_location"]);

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks too much .I am using JSON Framework. So i edited  NSMutableDictionary *data1 = [responseData objectFromJSONData]; to
to NSString *responseString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Answer (score 0):

I am using SBJson to parse json data. 
In general, call `[responseString JSONValue]` to get parsed data.
You can google it for detail reference.